# Can Gatsby integrate with 3rd party ui framework

Tags: gatsby

Currently we are using onsen.io as our react UI framework

as i understand gatsby is a react development framework, which help to build PWA easier

therefore it should compatible with other UI framework

however since gatsby force people to use reach/route library, which other UI framework may prefer to use other (such some mobile first UI framework, to create mobile UI experience)

im really interesting that "Can gatsby compatible with this or other UI framework"

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, Gatsby is Static Site Generator. Building `PWA` apps is a small part of it.

Gatsby use React, that's mean everything can work with React, it can work with Gatsby for sure, because Gatsby just wrap all React components and build them into static files.

Gatsby use `@reach/router` inside, but if you really need use another, just go with it. I don't see any problem here.

Hope this help.